# Speeding up algorithm that finds multiples in a given range

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm a stumped on how to speed up my algorithm which sums multiples in a given range. This is for a problem on codewars.com here is a link to the problem
[codewars link](http://www.codewars.com/kata/54bb6ee72c4715684d0008f9/train/python)

Here's the code and i'll explain what's going on in the bottom

```
import itertools

def solution(number):
        return multiples(3, number) +  multiples(5, number) - multiples(15, number)

def multiples(m, count):

    l = 0
    for i in itertools.count(m, m):
        if i < count:
            l += i
        else:
            break
    return l

print solution(50000000) #takes 41.8 seconds
#one of the testers takes 50000000000000000000000000000000000000000 as input

# def multiples(m, count):
#     l = 0
#     for i in xrange(m,count ,m):
#         l += i
#     return l
```

so basically the problem ask the user return the sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 within a number. Here are the testers.

```
test.assert_equals(solution(10), 23)
test.assert_equals(solution(20), 78)
test.assert_equals(solution(100), 2318)
test.assert_equals(solution(200), 9168)
test.assert_equals(solution(1000), 233168)
test.assert_equals(solution(10000), 23331668)
```

my program has no problem getting the right answer.  The problem arises when the input is large. When pass in a number like 50000000 it takes over 40 seconds to return the answer. One of the inputs i'm asked to take is 50000000000000000000000000000000000000000, which a is huge number. That's also the reason why i'm using `itertools.count()` I tried using `xrange` in my first attempt but range can't handle numbers larger than a c type long.  I know the slowest part the problem is the multiples method...yet it is still faster then my first attempt using list comprehension and checking whether  `i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0`, any ideas guys?

Comment: real optimization would be a different approach all together. you don't need to iterate over all of the numbers in range, there is a closed form solution for this problem

Comment: I googled closed-form and the definition I got was, "An equation is said to be a closed-form solution if it solves a given problem in terms of functions and mathematical operations from a given generally-accepted set. For example, an infinite sum would generally not be considered closed-form".  After reading it, i'm still confused on what it means to be closed form. Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: by close form i mean you can come up with a simple arithmetic function which given a number n and a range r will give you the answer of how many multiples of n there are in the range [0..r]

Comment: I know how to calculate the number of multiples in a given range or number, I tried that before. I was able to calculate how many multiples of 3 and 5 for in a number by using ⌊b/n⌋ - ⌈a/n⌉ + 1 which, I read about here http://www.had2know.com/academics/count-multiples-within-range-calculator.html, I didn't know how to apply that though because the problem is asking for the sum of all the multiples in a given range, e.g. 3, 6, 9 = 18, vs there are 3 multiples of 3 in 9.

Comment: you'll be happy to hear there's also a closed form formula for computing the sum of an arithmetic sequence :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution should be faster for large numbers.

```
def solution(number):
    number -= 1
    a, b, c = number // 3, number // 5, number // 15
    asum, bsum, csum = a*(a+1) // 2, b*(b+1) // 2, c*(c+1) // 2
    return 3*asum + 5*bsum - 15*csum
```

---

**Explanation:**

Take any sequence from 1 to n:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n
```

And it's sum will always be given by the formula `n(n+1)/2`. This can be proven easily if you consider that the expression `(1 + n) / 2` is just a shortcut for computing the average, or [Arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of this particular sequence of numbers. Because `average(S) = sum(S) / length(S)`, if you take the average of any sequence of numbers and multiply it by the length of the sequence, you get the sum of the sequence.

If we're given a number n, and we want the sum of the multiples of some given k up to n, including n, we want to find the summation:

```
k + 2k + 3k + 4k + ... xk
```

where xk is the highest multiple of k that is less than or equal to n. Now notice that this summation can be factored into:

```
k(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + x)
```

We are given k already, so now all we need to find is x. If x is defined to be the highest number you can multiply k by to get a natural number less than or equal to n, then we can get the number x by using Python's integer division:

```
n // k == x
```

Once we find x, we can find the sum of the multiples of any given k up to a given n using previous formulas:

```
k(x(x+1)/2)
```

Our three given k's are 3, 5, and 15.

We find our x's in this line:

```
a, b, c = number // 3, number // 5, number // 15
```

Compute the summations of their multiples up to n in this line:

```
asum, bsum, csum = a*(a+1) // 2, b*(b+1) // 2, c*(c+1) // 2
```

And finally, multiply their summations by k in this line:

```
return 3*asum + 5*bsum - 15*csum
```

And we have our answer!

Comment: The solution worked! Could you please explain how it's working and why it works so well?

Comment: @msanti Related: [Simple sum calculator](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/82551/12680)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I see now lol thanks Shashanks for the awesome explanation and thanks for the links @yurib and Ashwini.

Comment: @msanti Great question! Let me know if more explanation is necessary. :)